# UIPickerView selection array Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uipickerview

Currently, I got my code to work correctly, but the problem I'm having issue with the UIPickerView.  Right now, If I select Cameron brand, it goes to var Cameron but if i select Shaffer brand, it still goes to var Cameron.

How can I rewrite the code so when I pick a different brand, it select a different array?

For example, if I select brand cameron, it select cameron, if i select brand Shaffer, it pick shaffer, etc.

```
class Picker: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate

{
    var activeTextField:UITextField?

    @IBOutlet var pickerView1: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var pickerView2: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var pickerView3: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textField2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textField3: UITextField!

    var brand = ["Cameron","Shaffer", "Hydril"]
    var cameron = ["D Annular Preventer", "UM Ram Preventer", "U Ram Preventer"]
    var shaffer = ["Spherical Annular Preventer", "LXT Ram Preventer", "NXT Ram Preventer"]
    var size = ["7 1/16","11","13 5/8"]
    var size2 = ["8 5/8","12","15 5/8"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerView1 = UIPickerView()
        pickerView2 = UIPickerView()
        pickerView3 = UIPickerView()

        pickerView1.tag = 0
        pickerView2.tag = 1
        pickerView3.tag = 2 

    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int  {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return brand.count
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return cameron.count
        } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
            return size.count
        }
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return brand[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return cameron[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
            return size[row]
        }
        return ""
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {

        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            textField1.text = brand[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            textField2.text = cameron[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
            textField3.text = size[row]
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Lacking the energy to type out the answer, are you able to understand / use Dictionaries instead of hardcoded array literals here, so you can associate each brand with its allowable values? That way the allowable-value-array can be looked up based on *using the brand as a key*.

Comment: I haven't used dictionaries before.  It's something I may need to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cameron` has to be replaced with a dynamic lookup. You'll need a dictionary of brands, which you can then tie to the UI:

[As I was writing this up I found the variable names awful; please avoid 0, 1, 2, insanity of numbering your variables, 3, 4, bleah]

At class level:

```
var brandLookup = [ "cameron": [ "x", "y", "z"], "anotherBrand": ... ]
```

then your delegate functions:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        return brand.count
    } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        let brand = textField1.text
        let modelsForBrand = brandLookup[brand]!
        return modelsForBrand.count
    }
    ...
}
```

similarly:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {
   if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        textField1.text = brand[row]
        pickerView2.reloadAllComponents() // this picker has new data now
   } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
       let brand = textField1.text
       let modelsForBrand = brandLookup[brand]!
       textField2.text = modelsForBrand[row]
   }
...
}
```

Finally:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    // left as an exercise for you
}
```

Comment: So, I'm assuming to replace the picker view code 

' func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return brand.count
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        let brand = textField1.text
        let modelsForBrand = brandLookup[brand]!
        return modelsForBrand[row]
        
        return 1
    } '

Comment: I got the coding to work with the exception of the code "return modelsForBrand[row].count"..it getting me the "Use of unresolved identifier 'row' ".......if i put in return 3...it works...thanks.

Comment: Fixed... `count` is a property of an array, and I had `row` out of context. Avoid hardcoded values! Turns your code into unstable garbage.